# Communicating with a 12V device?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

I'd like to connect a [12V access control device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Security-RFID-Proximity-Entry-Door-Lock-Access-Control-System-Quality-5YOA/32283856982.html) to the Arduino, but I lack the understanding.

How can the signals from and to the device be done when they have different voltages?

I am afraid that the 12V would brick the Arduino.

Comment: Opto-isolators are your friend here...

Comment: D0 an D1 are weigand26 for external reader. it should be 5 V

Comment: @Juraj Interesting. I can't find info on this, and the vendor doesn't understand my question. I guess I'll just buy it and measure it myself.

Comment: where do you see that this version has D0 D1 pins?

Comment: @Juraj I'm sorry, I linked the wrong one. I fixed the link. [Here it is here as well](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Security-RFID-Proximity-Entry-Door-Lock-Access-Control-System-Quality-5YOA/32283856982.html).

Comment: here is the info about weigand26  https://www.dhgate.com/store/product/rfid-proximity-entry-door-lock-access-control/168634282.html

Comment: @Juraj Hmmm, I don't see the D0, D1 pins on this one. Are they labeled differently?

Comment: down on the page is a table. it mentions it as option. it is input only for additional reader

Comment: @Juraj Yes, I saw the table. I was talking about the pictures, as they don't have those pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [opto-coupler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator):

> An opto-isolator (also called an optocoupler, photocoupler, or optical
> isolator) is an electronic component that transfers electrical signals
> between two isolated circuits by using light. Opto-isolators
> prevent high voltages from affecting the system receiving the
> signal. Commercially available opto-isolators withstand
> input-to-output voltages up to 10 kV and voltage transients with
> speeds up to 25 kV/μs.
>
> A common type of opto-isolator consists of an LED and a
> phototransistor in the same opaque package. Other types of
> source-sensor combinations include LED-photodiode, LED-LASCR, and
> lamp-photoresistor pairs. Usually opto-isolators transfer digital
> (on-off) signals, but some techniques allow them to be used with
> analog signals.

Here is an example schematic and packaging:

[image: Optocouple]

If you have a heavy load (although this does not seem to be your case) then they can also be used in conjunction with relays - here is an eight channel opto-coupler relay module board:

> [image: 12V 8 Channel Level Trigger Optocoupler Relay Module For Arduino]
>
> [image: 12V 8 Channel Level Trigger Optocoupler Relay Module For Arduino showing optocouples]

Comment: I see. So the way this would work is:  

- 12V power to the access control.
- 5V power to the Arduino.
- A wire from the D0, D1 pin on the access control, to the opto-coupler, and a wire from it to the Arduino in a digital pin.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Majenko Can you please tell me if my comment above is accurate?

Comment: An opto-coupler is like an LED on one side and like button on the other. You treat it pretty much like those items.

Comment: On the input side of the board, connect an Arduino output pin to the the input of one of the opto- or relay inputs. Connect the Arduino Ground (and +5v if the board calls for it) to the respective board inputs. On the output side of the board, If the access device just needs a contact closure, connect those two device connections to the Common and Normally Open contacts of the same opto where you connected the Arduino pin. Or if the device needs switched 12v, Connect +12v to the Common contact and the device's switched input to the Normally Open contact.